# Output of values from multiple subnets created using a for_each loop

Tags: azure, foreach, module, terraform, output

I've created some subnets using a for_each loop like below

main.tf in child module

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "obc_subnet" {
name                  = var.subnet_name
address_prefixes      = var.address_prefixes
resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
virtual_network_name  = var.vnet_name
}
```

main.tf in root module

```
module "deploy_subnet" {
  source              = "./modules/azure_subnet"
  for_each              = var.prefix
  subnet_name           = each.value["name"]
  address_prefixes      = [each.value["cidr"]]
  subscription_id       = var.subscription_id
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  region                = var.region
  vnet_name             = var.vnet_name
}
```

variables.tf in root module

```
variable "prefix" {
  type  = map(object({
    name = string
    cidr = string
  }))
  default = {
    sub-1 = {
      name = "aks-sn"
      cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
    }
    sub-2 = {
      name = "postgres-sn"
      cidr = "10.0.2.0/24"
    }
    sub-3 = {
      name = "keyvault-sn"
      cidr = "10.0.3.0/24"
    }
  }
}
```

Thats all working fine except when I try and output the values associated with the 3 subnets (id for example)

I'm trying to use the for k syntax in the output but I'm not really understanding how it should look.

I have the below in my output.tf of the child module

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, subnets in azurerm_subnet.obc_subnet : k => subnets.id
      })
}
```

I wasnt really sure how to approach the output.tf in my root module so I left it as is

```
output "subnet_id" {
  value = module.deploy_subnet.subnet_id
}
```

I'm getting an error that the value has no attributes

```
Error: 

Unsupported attribute
  on modules/azure_subnet/output.tf line 3, in output "subnets_id":
   3:     for k, subnets in azurerm_subnet.obc_subnet : k => subnets.is

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but the other way around.

The `azurerm_subnet` resource in the child module is not a collection, so the output there should be just:

```
output "subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.obc_subnet.id
}
```

But in the root module you have the collection of child modules. Thus for example:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = {
    for k, subnet in module.deploy_subnet : k => subnet.subnet_id
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! thank you and now i understand what you mean about the collection of child modules. The root module is effectively calling the child module 3 times so this is where the configuration needs to be. so now I get an output but its all together in one. Any ideas how to create it so that its doing an individual output for each subnet? or does that require a different approach altogether

Comment: I got it working just by doing this per item in my root module

output "subnet1_name" {
  value = module.deploy_subnet["sub-1"].subnet_name
    }
output "subnet2_name" {
  value = module.deploy_subnet["sub-2"].subnet_name
    }
output "subnet3_name" {
  value = module.deploy_subnet["sub-3"].subnet_name
    }

Comment: In the answer the output is a `map`, indexed with same keys as in `var.prefix`.

What's your use case for the outputs? In case of remote state you can use it at any `map`. Or from `terraform output` you can e.g. pipe to `jq` for filtering.